# Calling a shared library using ./

Tags: c

I am curious about using `dlopen` in Linux to call shared libraries.
Suppose I want to use a shared library in C whose name is `fileName.so`. I am working in a 64bit Ubuntu Linux and I include `dlfcn.h` and use `dlopen` function to access the shared library.

When I use `dlopen(fileName.so, RTLD_LAZY)`, a NULL handle is returned and shared library is not opened. However, when I use `dlopen("./fileName.so", RTLD_LAZY)` the `dlopen` does its job and opens the shared library. It seems that the main point is in using `./` before file name.

It is appreciated if help me figure out why I should use `./` in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POSIX says that [`dlopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html) has to know where to look for the file and leaves the behaviour when the file name does not include a `/` implementation defined.  On Linux, if you don't supply a pathname (a name with a `/` in it somewhere), then [`dlopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) only looks in 'standard places', specified by environment variables such as LD_LIBRARY_PATH or via `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or `/etc/ld.so.cache`; see also `ldconfig(8)`) or in standard places such as `/lib` and `/usr/lib`.

When you specify the relative name `./fileName.so`, it knows to look in the current directory, which is not normally a place it looks.

Note that you can run into some interesting issues on systems that support both 32-bit and 64-bit executables, with various conventions being used for the locations of the different classes of library.  Other variants of Unix use vaguely related systems — mostly using `dlopen()` et al these days (historically, it was not always thus), and using a wide variety of environment variables (DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, LIBPATH, SHLIB_PATH, LD_RUN_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32, LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64, ...).

Comment: For detail on the places dlopen() looks by default, see the Linux [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) for it.

Comment: @HevyLight: thanks for the URL.  I've lifted it into the answer, along with the POSIX specification URL.

Answer (score 1):

`./` is a relative path to the `.so` file. It means that the file is in the current directory.

In *nix, by default, when given a file name without an absolute or relative path, `dlopen` will search for the library in a set [list of default locations](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen).

Comment: Libraries are not searched for using `$PATH` on Linux (or Unix generally); that is a Windows trick for DLLs.

Comment: $PATH is usually for binaries in Linux Environment.

Answer (score 0):

The "main point" is in using double-quotes in your second example:

```
    dlopen("./fileName.so", RTLD_LAZY)
```

If you want to include your own library/filename enclose it in double-quotes.  You don't even need the `./` for that, provided that the file is in the current directory, as `./` suggests.

As per the dlopen manpage's example:

```
    handle = dlopen("libm.so", RTLD_LAZY);
       if (!handle) {
           fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
```

the filename is enclosed in quotes.

Though, as specified by a previous answer, dlopen will look in the "standard" places for "includes".  Another way of including a library that's inside your working directory (though, obviously, not a shared system library) is to use the preprocessor directive with the filename enclosed within double quotes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "myCustomLibrary.h"
```